# SHDocVw.WebBrowserClass register to refresh event

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, .net-2.0, shdocvw

is there a way to know when the user perform refresh to the page using the
SHDocVw.WebBrowserClass of ie using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a better way but you can consider using Before_Navigate it should be triggered by refresh as well.

**EDIT :**

I've just checked the documentation apparently refresh doesn't trigger these, sorry.

I think there is no easy to way to this, you might want to try the following component :

http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/

It's a very nice webbrowser control implementation, using C++ for tricky parts, and got a refreshbegin event that you can use.

Comment: and how can i know when refresh complete?

Comment: Be careful that this event will be triggered in every navigation not only refresh you might wanna check the URL to understand the refresh. I can't remember the parameters there can be an indicator in them as well.

Comment: I'm sorry its not working... not the before_nevigate and nevigatecomplete, i tried the before_nevigate2 and  nevigatecomplete2 and its not working neither